# Rails - HTML page won't take full height

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a tutorial in an attempt to create an admin panel, but I got stuck at some point. I'm trying to make the navabar + text to take full height, but they are somewhat 'wrap content'.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEAM 21 </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'adminpanel', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <!-- <%= javascript_include_tag 'adminpanel', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> -->
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
  <% end %>

  <%if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
  <% end %>

  <!-- HEADER
  ================================================== -->
  <div class="containter-fluid display-table">
        <div class="row display-table-row">
          <!-- Side menu -->
          <div class="col-md-2 display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
            <h1> Navigation </h1>

          </div>

          <!-- Main content area -->
          <div class="col-md-10 box display-table-cell valign-top">

            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
               Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
               the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>

            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
               Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
               the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- CONTENT
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="buffer-top">
      <!-- <%= yield %> -->
    </div>


   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
   ================================================== -->
   <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"


html body
  font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
  background-color: #f3f3f4
  color: #676a6c
  height: 100%



.box
  border: 1px red dotted


#side-menu
  background-color: #2f4050
  padding: 0px

#side-menu h1
  color: #1f3647
  text-align: center
  margin: 10px 0px
  font-size: 25px

.display-table
  display: table
  padding: 0px
  height: 100%

.display-table-row
  display: table-row
  height: 100%

.display-table-cell
  display: table-cell
  height: 100%
  float: none

.valign-top
  vertical-align: top
```

Edit: I forgot to mention. I've tried all the solutions that I could find, but it just won't go full height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not css. I assume this is sass? Check for body margin. Usually it's `10px`. Else make your html to height 100% too

```
html
  height: 100%
```

Comment: When you just have `body` as `100%` and `html` is `0px` high, then body is `100%` of `0px` and thus still `0px`. So usually remember to set html height as well :)

Comment: I had them like that, but they were on the same line

Comment: Aaah, okay, i understand